# How to get all keys of a Javascript Object without a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework

I have an Object and I want to be able to search for the name of the software. For this example we will use "Adobe Acrobat".

```
const SoftwareDict {

"Actuate": {
              "Standard": "Retire",
           },
"Adobe Acrobat": {
              "Adobe Acrobat Pro DC": "Mainstream",
              "Adobe Acrobat Professional 7.0.8": "Retire",
              "Adobe Acrobat Professional 9.0.0":"Retire",
              "Adobe Acrobat Professional X":"Retire",
              "Adobe Acrobat Professional XI":"Contain",
              "Adobe Acrobat Reader 7.0.8":"Retire",
              "Adobe Acrobat Reader 9.0.0":"Retire",
              "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC":"Mainstream",
              "Adobe Acrobat Reader X":"Retire",
              "Adobe Acrobat Reader XI":"Contain",
           },
};
```

When I know the key I am searching for it works:

```
session.send(SoftwareDict["Adobe Acrobat"]["Adobe Acrobat Pro DC"]);
```

The issue I come across is when I am trying to use a loop to get the key names from my object and store the values in the "choices" array. I have tried a for loop and the forEach method but neither have worked. When I run offline in the Bot Framework Channel Emulator the loop works perfectly. I am currently running on the Azure Portal to use Entity Recognizer so I need it to work in this location.

Is there an issue with running loops on this Bot Framework portal. This is the first time I have needed to use them here.

```
bot.dialog('LifecycleWaterfallDialog', function (session, args) {
//Match Lifecycle to correct software using waterfall
        //Find Software Name
        var choices = [];
        session.send("Started");
        var softwareEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'Software');
        //Get List of Versions for that software
        if (softwareEntity) {

        session.send(SoftwareDict["Adobe Acrobat"]["Adobe Acrobat Pro DC"]); //This works & returns "Mainstream" 

        var versions = SoftwareDict["Adobe Acrobat"];
        versions.forEach(function(item){
            choices.push(item);
            session.send(item); //DOES NOT WORK
        });
        session.send(choices[0]); //DOES NOT WORK 

        //Outputs 
        session.send(SoftwareDict[softwareEntity.entity][choices[0]]); //testing first software version
        session.endDialog();
        } else {
            session.send("sorry");
            session.endDialog();
        }

}).triggerAction({
    matches: 'LifecycleStatus'
});
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(SoftwareDict).match(/adobe acrobat/i);` In all seriousness though, `Object.keys` returns all the keys of an object.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)` will return an array containing all the keys of `obj`

Comment: If you want us to help you figure out if there's something wrong with your code that has a loop in it, then you have to show us that code that has the loop in it and tell us exactly where it stops working.  Where's that code?  FYI, `.forEach()` is a method on an Array, not on a plain Object.  And, you can use `Object.keys(obj)` to get all the enumerable properties of an object into an array if that's something you need.  Also, "doesn't work" is not an appropriate description.  What exactly happens?  What error do you get or what result do you get?

Comment: Okay these all seem helpful I will try Object.keys out. Thank You.

Comment: Object Keys worked not sure how to award rep to all of the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will enumerate object properties for you

```
for (prop in versions) {
    choices.push(prop);
    session.send(prop);
}
```

Or as already mentioned in the comments - [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return you a list of keys you can then iterate e.g.

```
Object.keys(versions).forEach(...)
```

Comment: I'm curious how either of these are "without a loop" as in the title of the question.  Apparently, "without a loop" isn't really what the OP wanted.

Comment: @jfriend00 clearly neither do, the title doesn't really convey what the issue actually was (the OP didn't quite understand that `forEach` only works with arrays). Felt it was worth just mentioning `for..in`, it's arguably more readable than the latter.